# $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$, then $|a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}| \leq M|a_{n+1} - a_n|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If f is differential such that $|f'(x)| \leq M < 1$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$
Let $a_1$ be any real number and define $(a_n)$ by $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$

Then $|a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}| \leq M|a_{n+1} - a_n|$.

Is it directly from the Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Because
$$a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=f(a_{n+1})-f(a_n)=f'(x_0)(a_{n+1}-a_n)$$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. You can bound this by $M|a_{n+1}-a_n|$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! That's directly from the MVT, as @M.Van explained.

Moreover, you can conclude that this sequence converges, because $M < 1$!

Comment: How would you like to prove this? Because if $(a_n)$ is a sequence, $|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|<|a_{n+1}-a_n|$ for all $n$ does not imply $(a_n)$ converges. Consider the famous counterexample: 
$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}.$$
Now we know $(a_n)$ does not converge, while 
$$|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| = |\sum_{k=1}^{n+2}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k}|=\frac{1}{n+2}< \frac{1}{n+1} =|a_{n+1}-a_n|.$$

Comment: @M.Van ,  Luísa is rigth. If $M<1$, the sequence converges.  Note that, from  $$|a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}| \leq M|a_{n+1} - a_n|$$ it is easy to prove, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, 
$$|a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}| \leq M^n|a_2 - a_1|$$ 
So for all $p\in \mathbb{N}$, $p \geqslant 1$, 
$$|a_{n+p+1} - a_{n+1}| \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^p|a_{n+k+1} - a_{n+k}|\leqslant \left(\sum_{k=1}^p M^{n+k-1} \right)|a_2 - a_1|\leqslant \frac{M^{n}}{1-M}|a_2 - a_1|$$
So, since $M<1$,  the sequence is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: I see! very nice